# Flurry Cohort Analysis - How to track the Device ID?

Tags: xcode, swift, analysis, flurry

I integrated Flurry in my Xcode Swift developed app and it is working right now.

What I can't see is which Devive ID the users have. The only thing I can see is what kind of devices they use.

And based on this I also don't know how to do the Cohort Analysis. Do I need a specific Flurry Code?

Thanks for help :)

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Flurry reports anonime data, as expected. What should interest analists is what USERS are doing, not WHICH user is doing what.

From https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/events/ios/#events-best-practices:

> Important: It is a violation of Flurry’s TOS to record personally identifiable information such as a user’s UDID, email address, and so on using Flurry.